# Generic integer type conversion from and to string

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I want to convert any [integral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) type to an hexadecimal string representation and back. I came up with something like the following, but it obviously has errors. Any suggestion on doing that in C#? Thanks in advance.

```
public class HexCnv<T>
{
    public static T ToIntType(string sInput)
    {
        return T.Parse(sInput.TrimStart('0', 'x'));
    }

    public static string ToStringType(T nInput)
    {
        return "0x" + nInput.ToString("X2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [integral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) instead of integer?

Comment: Yep, integral type.

Comment: If you're going to strip `0x` from the input, then you should use `int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)` or `Convert.ToInt32(prefixedHex , 16);` - `0x123` is a very different value than `123` when parsed without specifying that it's a hex number

Comment: You won't be able to write such a generic method until C# 11 at least and the addition of [static abstract members in interfaces](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/static-abstracts-in-interfaces.md). `IAddable` is the typical example used in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with all your ideas, thanks a lot. I've tested the following code, it works the way I want and I made it with a *generic* sense; I could test other methods to check code efficiency, but it works for me and I hope this idea works for anyone else:

```
public class HexCnv<T> 
{
    private MethodInfo _mParse;
    private MethodInfo _mToString;
    private T _value;
    private bool _isPrimitive;

    public HexCnv(T v)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        _isPrimitive = t.IsPrimitive;
        _value = v;
        _mParse = t.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles) });
        _mToString = t.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    }

    public HexCnv(string v)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        _isPrimitive = t.IsPrimitive;
        _mParse = t.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles) });
        _mToString = t.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        FromString(v);
    }

    private void FromString(string s)
    {
        if (_isPrimitive && _mParse != null)
            _value = (T)_mParse.Invoke(null, new object[] { s.TrimStart('0', 'x'), NumberStyles.HexNumber });
    }

    public new string ToString()
    {
        string sOut = string.Empty;

        if (_isPrimitive) sOut = "0x" + _mToString.Invoke(_value, new object[] { "x2" }).ToString();
        return sOut;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(HexCnv<T> v) { return v._value; }

    public static implicit operator HexCnv<T>(T v) { return new HexCnv<T>(v); }

    public static implicit operator HexCnv<T>(string v) { return new HexCnv<T>(v); }
}
```

As you can see I changed the static methods, and made it works with simple assigning, see next snippet:

```
        HexCnv<short> mm = "0x1f55";

        Console.WriteLine("MM     = {0}", (int) mm);
        Console.WriteLine("MM-HEX = {0}", mm.ToString());

        //This produce the following result
        //  MM     = 8021
        //  MM-HEX = 0x1f55

        HexCnv<short> mm = "0x8f55"; //IDE show no errors on this, but
        HexCnv<short> mm = 0x8f55;   //It'll give an error on this expression,  
                                     //cuz the number is higher than "short"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a generic constraint that will limit generic parameters to integral types, and you can't call static methods (like `Parse`) on a generic type. You could either use implicit conversion and use `long` (or maybe `ulong`) everywhere, or provide overloads for each integral type - though you only need it for the `ToIntType` method since the `ToStringType` would give you the same result for a `byte` as a `byte` casted to a `long`.

Comment: I've considered about using `long` to cover all integral types, except for `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, but it will increase memory usage, mostly when the result of `public static T ToIntType(string sInput)` is placed onto more than 100000 instances of it.

Comment: Well you could always cast back to the original type (dealing with overflows, etc.) or just have 4 (or 8 if you need support for unsigned types) overloads, but that seems like a lot of work just to wrap a pretty simple parsing call.

Answer (score 0):

How's this work? (Not tested)

```
public class HexCnv<T>
{
    public static readonly TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T));
    
    public static T ToIntType(string sInput)
    {
        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
               return Int32.Parse(sInput.TrimStart('0', 'x'));
            case TypeCode.Int64:
               return Int64.Parse(sInput.TrimStart('0', 'x'));
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(sInput));
    }

    public static string ToStringType(T nInput)
    {
        return "0x" + nInput.ToString("X2");
    }
}
```

Comment: In `ToStringType` there's an error, cuz I cannot call `ToString` on e generic type. In the first method you need to make @D. Stanley fix in my question comment, but thanks for the head up.